# "Frenemies", or How to Make Teenagers Happy at a Birthday Party

Tags: cluster-analysis, combinatorics, mathematical-optimization

I have a combinatorial optimization problem that I am struggling with.  The technical details of the problem are cumbersome, so I have translated things in terms of a fictitious sweet-16 birthday party.  Obviously, teenagers are NP difficult, but that's separate from the actual problem I'm trying to solve.

Let's say I have a son who is about to turn 16. He invites all of his friends for his birthday party, but not all of his friends like each other. In fact, every friend of my son's has at least one person they don't like, and some have more. These "frenemies" refuse to sit at the same table if one or more sworn "frenemy" is sitting at the same table. My son has provided me a list of all his invited friends, and also who doesn't like who. This information is symmetrical (If friend A doesn't like friend B, friend B doesn't like friend A), but it is NOT transitive (If friend A doesn't like friend B, but likes friend C, friend C is still free to like or dislike friend B). My question is: How do I determine the minimum number of tables that satisfies the condition that no two "frenemies" are seated at the same table?

Answer (score 1):

This is a combinatorial optimization problem, not a machine learning problem.

Actually, it is a coloring problem: Create a graph `G`, where each vertex corresponds to a person. An edge `(u, v)` exists iff the two persons `u` and `v` do not like each other. You are now asking for the smallest `k` such that `G` is `k`-colorable. A coloring `c(v)` tells you which table person `v` is seated at.

Now you just have to [pick an algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring#Algorithms).

Comment: A "greedy" approach won't provide an optimal solution in general:
Assume the following graph: A-B-C-D
If you start you search at node B and select C (what is at this point as good as selecting A), you end up with a solution requiering three tables, but the optimal solution is to group A, B and C, D.

Comment: @Reinhard: I updated my answer. Please let me know if you find a problem!

Comment: Yes, I agree with your new solution.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds more like a constrained optimisation problem than a machine learning problem to me. I would model it as follows.

- One variable per friend, the value would be the table,
- additional constraints (as per list) of the form `friendX !- friendY` to say that these two can't sit at the same table.

That's the basic model that you can solve using a constraint solver of your choice (I recomment [Minion](http://minion.sf.net)). You can either minimise the highest table number (which would require some additional constraints), or simply try to find a solution with a given number of tables (i.e. values in the domains of the variables) until you get down to one where no solution exists.

Depending on the size of the problem (i.e. number of friends and tables) this may or may not work. Something you may have to consider is the symmetry in the problem (i.e. the people on table A can move to table B and vice versa and it's still a solution) which could be broken with additional constraints.